# MySQL perfomance: letting a UNIQUE field generate an error or manually checking it

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

Theoretical question about the impact on performance.

One of the fields in my table is unique. For instance, email_address in the Users table.

What has less of an impact on performance? Attempting to add an already existing email address and getting the error, or doing a search on the email field?

Comment: Getting the error has to be better as you will still have to perform another query afterwards to actually insert your address if it is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UNIQUE field will probably be faster.

If you tell MySQL that a certain field is unique, it *may* perform some optimizations.

Additionally, if you want to insert the record if it isn't in the table already you might run into some concurrency issues. Assume there are two people trying to register with the same email address. Now, if you perform the uniqueness check yourself something like so:

```
bool exists = userAlreadyExists(email);

if (exists)
   showWarning();
else
   insertUser(email);
```

something like the following might happen:

```
User 1 executes userAlreadyExists("foo@example.com") // returns false
User 2 executes userAlreadyExists("foo@example.com") // returns false

User 1 executes insertUser("foo@example.com")
User 2 executes insertUser("foo@example.com") // which is now a duplicate
```

If you let MySQL perform the uniqueness check, the above won't happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you check then update, you have to query the database twice. And its turn it will check the table index twice. You have both network overhead and database processing overhead.

My *point of view* is you have to be optimistic: update and handle gracefully the potential failure if there is some duplicate values.

---

The two-steps approach has one other drawback: don't forget there will be concurrent access to your database. Depending on you database setup (isolation level, database engine), there is a potential that DB was modified by an other connection between the `SELECT` and your `UPDATE`.

Comment: Both this and the other answer point out concurrency, which is a valid point. Having the DB use a unique field will prevent this. The other person was just a minute quicker so I'm awarding the correct answer to that person. Still thanks for the insight.